# Add a header to a .csv column that already has data

Tags: powershell

I have a .csv file that has data in a column, I need that column to have a header. I can not figure out how to get a header in the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
import-csv test.csv -Header "Name" | export-csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```