# How do I add headers into a CSV that does not have one?

Tags: powershell, csv

May sound easy but I can't get it work...

```
$file = 'D:\TESTING.csv'

Set-Content $file "1,2,3"

$file = import-csv $file -Header a , b , c | export-csv $file 

echo $file
```

Desired output:

```
a b c
- - -
1 2 3
```

actual output:

```
nothing
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a header to a .csv column that already has data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244959/add-a-header-to-a-csv-column-that-already-has-data)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's this line:

> ```
> $file = import-csv $file -Header a , b , c | export-csv $file
> ```

You're piping the data into the `export-csv` cmdlet. There is no output from that command, so `$file` would be null. Also `$file` contains the path of your output. Why would you change it to be file content?

Assuming that you want to both export the data and keep it in the session, you could just do something like this instead:

```
$filedata = import-csv $file -Header a , b , c  
$filedata | export-csv $file -NoTypeInformation
```

You could also do it in one line with [`Tee-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx)

```
Import-CSV $file -Header a , b , c | Tee-Object -Variable $filedata | Export-CSV $file -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
import-csv test.csv -Header "Name" | export-csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```